# Best way to make a feature strip background with CSS?

Tags: css, layout, html, background, strip

I was wondering what would be the best way to create a feature strip of background in a website layout?

The approach that comes to mind, would be to create an absolute positioned div with a z-index of -1 and adjust top/height to match up behind a fixed layout.

Is this a good way to go about it? Or is there a better way?

Thank you for any help! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more semantic approach would be to apply the background strip to an element on the page -- in the case of your example, the "slideshow" element. This element's outer constraint (whether that be a `div`, a `ul`, or something else) can then be stretched to 100% of the width of the page, and the content of the element centered (or positioned as desired).

This approach would be more maintainable than some other approaches -- content could be added before the element without breaking the layout, the strip could be changed without much effort, etc.

Background scaling could be taken care of in several ways:

1. Make your background big enough that it isn't likely to ever be a problem.
2. Use a tile-able background.
3. Use CSS3 `background-size` property. [A jsfiddle example is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/narthur/ppEsU/1/) ([Not supported in <=IE8](http://www.standardista.com/css3/css3-background-properties/#bg11), but with a little creativity could degrade gracefully.)
4. Put the image inside your div (or similar) and then use CSS to position absolutely, set the z-index to force below the content, and stretch the image to the width and height of the element. [Here's a jsfiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/narthur/Ahq2Z/1/) (Note: UNSEMANTIC! Reduces maintainability, etc. But does have better support than CSS3 `background-size`...)

Comment: As an addendum to 1) - also ensure that the sides of your image blend as seamlessly as possible with your background colour. Notice on the page you linked to that the sides of the bokeh image have a slight gradient to make the transition to a colour less harsh.

You can also use something like <a href="http://srobbin.com/blog/jquery-plugins/jquery-backstretch/" title="The Backstretch jQuery plugin">Backstretch</a> as a fallback for browsers that don't support <a href="http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/">background sizing</a>.

Comment: @Ed-M Good points! Love the jQuery fallback idea! On the topic of the transition between the background image to the normal site background color, the example that Jess provided also uses borders for that purpose. This could either be worked into the background image, or created using CSS with a little ingenuity. (Try to keep it semantic!)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :D Sounds like a really good approach. I've been trying to get it to work, but I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. Does the slideshow element and div holding it have to be separate from the main wrap holding the layout together?

Comment: @Jess Added a fiddle for option four. Note: This is the most UNSEMANTIC option! I would suggest using option three and then using Ed-M's jquery link as a fallback as a much better approach.

Comment: @Jess Added yet another option, this time for the more semantic option number three. Note that the linked-to fiddle does not contain the jQuery fallback script that Ed-M linked to.

Answer (score 3):

A div containing an image placed behind the content is probably the best way to make a scaling background.

I think CSS3 also supports [background scaling](http://www.dropthenerd.com/css3-and-scaling-background-images/), but it is not widely supported.

Answer (score 1):

Number of websites "cheat" : the site's background image already have the strip on it

It's simple and painless but it's static.